# What are the possible formats of the DOCKER_HOST URLs?

Tags: docker, docker-cli

Remote docker servers can be reached by the docker cli by settings the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable.

Mostly, `tcp://<hostname-or-ip>:<port>` or sometimes `ssh://<hostname-or-ip>:<port>` is used.

Unfortunately, the docker documentation talks about everything, except the possible URL formats of this variable. What are they, how do they work?

Comment: Just a note from the far future: docker documentation has the very common phenomenon, that it talks about everything, except what you have looked for. It is not your fault, it is theirs. Probably it is the worst documented software in the recent open source world. In general, I would suggest to not use docker if you do not need to, it is very likely that you should use [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) for which you used docker until now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parsing of the `DOCKER_HOST` variable happens in the `parseDockerDaemonHost` function in the [`opts/hosts.go`](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/opts/hosts.go) source fragment of the docker-cli.

The possible values are the following:

- `tcp://1.2.3.4:2375` - it connects to the docker server at the TCP port 2375 of the remote system. Beside the IP, also the hostname can be used. Leaving out the port field, it defaults to 2375 in normal mode, or to 2376 if we use TLS encryption (docker client should be called with the `--tls` flag for that).
- `unix:///path/to/socket` - it connects to a docker server listening on the local unix socket `/path/to/socket`. Unix sockets exist only on Linux (& co) systems. The path does not need to be an absolute one. The default value is `/var/run/docker.sock` (is connected if `DOCKER_HOST=unix://`).
- `npipe:///./pipe/docker_engine` - named pipes are similar to the Unix sockets, but in the Windows world. It probably connects a local docker server running on a Windows. Note, docker on Windows runs on a Linux VM, over the HyperV virtualization engine of the Microsoft. And it is reached probably over the virtual network provided by the HyperV. Native Windows docker is not very widely used.
- `fd://1.2.3.4:5678` - Contrary its name, it has probably nothing to do to file descriptors. It behaves similarly to the `tcp://`, except that the port number does not default to 2375. The exact working would probably need further digging in the docker-cli source.
- `ssh://1.2.3.4:22` - it calls the `ssh` command to remotely login the remote server. The `docker` command should be available there in the default `PATH`. There it executes a `docker` command, passing exactly the same arguments to it, with them we called it locally. Probably it can connect the docker server only on its default address (`/var/run/docker.sock`) on the remote side.

Protocol-less URLs (`//host:port`) default to `tcp://`. Any other URL formats are rejected with the `Invalid bind address format` error message.

The communication protocol is http(s), although I had some issues with it in proxied configurations.

Comment: What about protocoless URLs? The `docker-entrypoint.sh` here https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blame/master/20.10/docker-entrypoint.sh#L37 seems to imply that protocoless urls is possible like `//host:port`.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I think they default to tcp:// . I inserted it into the post.