# GitLab Runner setup with remote docker

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner

My setup requirements:
Server1: GitLab
Server2: GitLab runner
Server3: Docker Engine testing
Server4: Docker Engine production

Does Server 2 need also a docker engine installed?
How do i configure the runner for deployment on testing & production, depending on job?

My general steps so far:
Installed GitLab on srv1, Runner on srv2, docker engine on srv3 &4.
Now I'm stuck at the configuration of GitLab Runner, as I only find guides which describe the setup with docker on the same machine as the Ci/CD server.

Comment: There clearly is `host` option configuration in `[runners.docker]` described at https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section . `How do i configure the runner for deployment on testing & production, depending on job?` <- this question is too broad. You configure it the way you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Is there a good doc where I can find examples using the different configuration option? because I really dont get yet, how I use the host option... maybe like host = ssh://[docker-user]@[srv3 ip]?

Also, do I register 2 runners, for deployment on srv3 and 4 each?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62757127/what-are-the-possible-formats-of-the-docker-host-urls Use the google, luke. `do I register 2 runners` I think yes.